# Implementing boolean contains(Rectangle2D r) method of Shape interface

Tags: java, interface, implementation, contains, shapes

here is my Java problem:

My Circle class implements the Shape interface and thus it must implement all the methods required. I have a problem with the method boolean contains(Rectangle2D r) that "Tests if the interior of the Shape entirely contains the specified Rectangle2D". Now, Rectangle2D is an abstract class that does not provide (to the best of my poor knowledge) any method to get the coordinates of the corners of the rectangle. To be more precise: "The Rectangle2D class describes a rectangle defined by a location (x, y) and dimension (w x h). This class is only the abstract superclass for all objects that store a 2D rectangle. The actual storage representation of the coordinates is left to the subclass".

So how can I solve this?

Please find below a part of my code:

```
public class Circle implements Shape
{
private double x, y, radius;

public Circle(double x, double y, double radius)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
}

// Tests if the specified coordinates are inside the boundary of the Shape
public boolean contains(double x, double y)
{
    if (Math.pow(this.x-x, 2)+Math.pow(this.y-y, 2) < Math.pow(radius, 2))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

// Tests if the interior of the Shape entirely contains the specified rectangular area
public boolean contains(double x, double y, double w, double h)
{
    if (this.contains(x, y) && this.contains(x+w, y) && this.contains(x+w, y+h) && this.contains(x, y+h))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

// Tests if a specified Point2D is inside the boundary of the Shape
public boolean contains(Point2D p)
{
    if (this.contains(p.getX(), p.getY()))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

// Tests if the interior of the Shape entirely contains the specified Rectangle2D
public boolean contains(Rectangle2D r)
{
    // WHAT DO I DO HERE????
}
}
```

Comment: Is this homework? But you have no tag slot left...

Comment: What development environment are you using? Because your lack of knowledge about a particular class shouldn't be an issue as it should show you the available methods of `r` when you type `r.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Rectangle2D` inherits `getMaxX, getMaxY, getMinX, getMinY` from `RectangularShape`. So you can get the coords of the corners.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.html

See "Methods inherited from class java.awt.geom.RectangularShape".

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yes, but wouldn't that create a new rectangle object? I presume it doesn't expose the internal bounds rectangle. And then you've still got to call `getX()` `getY()` `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` on that object to test the 4 coords.

Answer (score 1):

Use PathIterator. Will work for all convex shapes

```
PathIterator it = rectangle.getPathIterator(null);
while(!it.isDone()) {
    double[] coords = new double[2];
    it.currentSegment(coords);
    // At this point, coords contains the coordinates of one of the vertices. This is where you should check to make sure the vertex is inside your circle
    it.next(); // go to the next point
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in view of your current implementation:

```
    public boolean contains(Rectangle2D r)
{
    return this.contains(r.getX(), r.getY(), r.getWidth(), r.getHeight());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend `Ellipse2D.Double` setting the width and the height to the same value.

```
Ellipse2D.Double(double x, double y, double w, double h)
```

Then you can use its `contains` method passing it the `Rectangle2D` corners (you have the left-top corner X and Y and also the width and the height, so calculating the corners is trivial). `true` returned for `contains` applied to all rectangle corners indicates that the circle contains the rectangle